# Menu list in IE6 sub not dropping

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

in IE6 the menu is appearing as a sub menu. i have taken shots to show the problem. according to superpreview, all elements have layout and cannot see wht the problem is. would appreciate some advice as i am not that experienced in css, hence my post. many thanks.

Screen grabs:

http://img36.imageshack.us/i/ie8menugrab.png/

http://img546.imageshack.us/i/ie6menugrab.png/

HTML

```
<div id="headermenu">


      <ul id="navigation" class="nav-main">
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="#">Freebies</a>
      <ul class="nav-sub">
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/backgrounds/">Backgrounds</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/buttons/">Buttons</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/graphics/">Graphics</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/html-css/">HTML &amp; CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/icons/">Icons</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/psd/">PSD</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/templates/">Templates</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/tutorials/">Tutorials</a></li>    
      </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="list"><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul class="nav-sub">
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/about/">AboutUs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/commercial-use/">Commercial Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/about/terms-of-use/">Terms Of Use</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>

        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/advertise/">Advertise</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>


    </ul>


  </div>
```

HEADER MENU CSS

```
#headermenu  {

  width: 999px;
  height:51px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*background-image: url(../images/headermenu.gif);*/
    background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

MENU CSS

```
#navigation {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    clear:both;
    width:999px;
    height:51px;
    background: #d6eaf8 url(../images/dropdown-bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
}


ul.nav-main,
ul.nav-main li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


ul.nav-main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
}

ul.nav-main li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}


ul.nav-main li.hover,
ul.nav-main li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../images/dropdown-bg-hover.gif) repeat-x left top;
}



ul.nav-main li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height: 51px;
    color: #999;
    font: 14px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url(../images/separator.gif) no-repeat right center;
}

ul.nav-main li a {
    display:block;
    padding: 16px 16px 0 16px;
    height: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    font: 14px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.nav-main li a:hover {
    color:#D6D6D6;
}



ul.nav-main *.list {
    padding-right: 22px;
    background: url(../images/navigation-arrow.gif) no-repeat right top;
}



ul.nav-sub {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    padding:10px;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    background: #353535 url(../images/dropdown-list-bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;

}


ul.nav-sub li {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 27px;
    float: none;
    width:145px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5a5a5a;
    background: none;
}

ul.nav-sub li a {
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    padding: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
    height: 15px;
    float: none;
    width:145px;
    background: none;
    font: 12px Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
}
```

Comment: My suggestion: drop support for IE6 -- it'll save you a lot of pain.

Comment: wish i could. blinking PITA. he needs to cater for every browser :-(

Comment: if one of my clients insists on IE6 support, I tell him that it'll double the cost development and reduce the functionality. that's often enough dissuade them. if they ask for "every browser", they're just being silly -- are they including IE5? IE4? Netscape? How far back do you go? IE6's market share has virtually vanished in the last year; there's really no good reason to be supporting it any more. (even IE7 is starting to drop off the radar now)

Comment: @Spudley: don't forget `telnet to port 80`, with full flash support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ul.nav-main li a` rule:

- set `display` to `inline-block`
- set `height` to `100%`.

This way the layout will be right but in IE6 the menu will be a little too high (double padding bug). I don't know how this affects the dropdown since I tested it only in SuperPreview.

And Lex is right, use `display:none/block` instead of `visibility:hidden/visible` for submenus.

Comment: note that `inline-block` has some serious bugs in IE6 (and IE7). use it, but make sure you test it.

Comment: @molnarm. how seriously should one take superpreview? for example, if choose 8 as base browser and then as target use either 8>7 or 7 it looks fine. in ie8 if i use comp mode it does not display the same.

Comment: @bollo I have no idea, but it should be the same because SP has the IE6 rendering engine built in and it uses the IE version installed on your computer to produce IE7, 8 and 9 previews.

Comment: @molnarm. that is exactly what is happening. SP is showing correct markup and each element haslayout in the DOM but not in comp mode in IE8. i do not have access to 6/7 to test. go figure :-)

Comment: @bollo IE8 comp mode is when it pretends to be an even worse browser than it really is, right? Why would anyone want to view your page using that? Anyway, if you want to see real browser renderings, try http://browsershots.org.

Comment: @molnarm i was under the impression that the comp mode was if a site was just catering for ie7 then it would format according to the specs of ie7? therefore if a client is using ie7 i need to know that my code is cross compatible. browsershots is too slow. tried spoon.net which seems ok for top browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code includes this:

```
ul.nav-main li:hover > ul { ... }
```

You are using the direct child selector (`>`), which is not supported by IE6.

Additionally, IE6 only supports `:hover` on `<a>` elements, so `li:hover` won't work in IE6.

Fortunately, there is a work-around for this, in the form of an HTC file called [Whatever:Hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

To use Whatever:Hover, download the htc file from the page linked above, then add the following to your CSS:

```
body {
    behavior:url("scripts/csshover.htc");
}
```

(preferably at the top of the stylesheet for readability, but it shouldn't matter which CSS file it's in)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @spudley this is happening when the menu is first displayed not on hover. what is the workaround for the > selector? many thanks

Comment: the work-around for `>` is simply a space selector. But as you probably already know, it's not the same, so if you've got nested lists, you'll have to add a class to each `<ul>` and `<li>` so you can reference them properly without any ambiguity.

Comment: @spudley. i have tried <li class="list"><a href="http://www.somedomain.com/category/backgrounds/">Backgrounds</a></li> on each element but still the same. thanks

Comment: just come back to this. i believe the problem in IE6 has to do with the anchor tag? there is an htc file that is loaded from body? anybody aware of this? thanks

Comment: @bollo: yes! I've edited the answer to include information about `:hover` in IE6 as well. :)

Comment: @spudley. it says to include as behaviour in body selector in css. my editor (komodo) it says 'unknown property' and in the browser it displays as the body tag. how exactly is this file called. thanks

Comment: @bollo -- it's `behavior`, not `behaviour`. You need to use the American spelling. Also, your editor may well say 'unknown property', because it's IE-specific and non-standard. It'll still work in IE; you'll just have to ignore the warning in the editor.

Comment: @spudley. this is what i have: behavior: url("/css/ie-css3.htc");

Comment: @spudley. this is the part i didn't get: the behavior URL must be relative to the HTML file you are serving rater than the CSS. can you explain please? thanks

Comment: @bollo: Since you've got a leading slash in the URL, you can ignore the 'relative' bit. They mean that if you say `url(xyz)` then it would look for the the `xyz` file in the directory where the HTML is, not where the CSS is. But with a leading slash, it's fine either way. (btw -- `ie-css3.htc` isn't the one I pointed you to for fixing hover. it should be `csshover3.htc`)

Comment: @spudley. for some strange reason i renamed it to what i posted grrr..however, i have unzipped archive and used behavior: url(/css/csshover3.htc); the htc file is is the css folder in root and it still is not working. should this behavior be in the menu css or the html css? thanks

Comment: @bollo - it's long time since I've used it (I stopped supporting IE6 ages ago). it needs to be styled for the `body` element. it shouldn't matter which CSS file it's in. I'll edit the answer to give an example.

Comment: @spudley. that is what i have in css file and still not working. i am using ietester would that make a difference. thanks

Comment: @bollo - that should work. Try testing it with a small test page to isolate any other issues that might be clouding the issue.

Comment: @spudley. would it be worth reposting my code in thethis thread or create a new one? thanks

Comment: @bollo -- yes, it probably would be worth starting a new question  :)

Comment: @spudley. thank you very much for all your help. may see you in the next question :-)

Comment: @spudley because i am not logged in i cannot do that. i tried. wish i could. i do not have openid.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one more rule:

```
ul.nav-sub{
    display:none;
}

ul.nav-main li:hover ul.nav-sub {
    display:block; /* OR display:list-item */
}
```

Comment: i have tried to various ways with your suggestion and menu is still the same. thanks

Comment: I made a correction because I made a mistake, this should work... if it doesn't I'm looking forward for an answer too...

Comment: get looking :-) still the same. here is what  used: ul.nav-main li:hover ul.nav-sub {     display:block; /* OR display:list-item */ } ul.nav-sub {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 display:none;
 padding:10px;
 top: 48px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 598;
 background: #353535 url(../images/dropdown-list-bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;

}

Comment: just come back to this. i believe the problem in IE6 has to do with the anchor tag? there is an htc file that is loaded from body? anybody aware of this? thanks